# Top align images in subfigure/minipage with adjustbox when one caption spills over to next line

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, subcaption, adjustbox

I am trying to use the `adjustbox` package to vertically align two subfigures (which, as I understand, are `minipages`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My Slide}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{centering}
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{Short caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}}%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{Longer caption that spills over to next line}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}}
    \end{centering}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It's important to see which packages you're using, especially in this context (some people are still using obsolete packages like `subfig` or `subfigure` instead of the current `subcaption`).

Comment: Any news? Does answers below solve your problem? If they, please select one which you most liked (and will use it in your document(s)  and accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include which document class you are using. I will use `article` class as example. As commented by @Miyase. You need provide a full MWE which include the code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. More details you can take a look [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). You don't need `adjustbox` here. The `subfigure` have its own alignment specification in the option args. If you want the figures to be aligned, depends on the location of the caption you can choose `t` or `b` alignment. Normally figure's caption will be at the bottom of the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\caption{Short caption}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\caption{Longer caption that spills over to next line}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Short caption}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Longer caption that spills over to next line}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Answer your comment: You could manually add a `\vskip`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My Slide}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{centering}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{Short caption}\vskip11pt
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{Longer caption that spills over to next line}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{centering}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated my post to include the document class. For the first of the images you post, is there a way to top-align the captions? Ie. so that the lines beginning with (a) and (b) are on the same line?

Comment: @Elif You wanna the a,b on the same line, and in the same time the figures are also aligned?

Comment: Exactly! Trying to get a, b lines of caption aligned and figures also aligned in the first of your examples.

Comment: @Elif I add a method in the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much Tom!

Answer (score 0):

Using `adjustbox` the desired result you will get if you change `\valign=t` to `valign=b`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\adjustbox{valign=b}{
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\caption{Short caption}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{subfigure}}%
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=b}{
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\caption{Longer caption that spills over to next line}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
\end{subfigure}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as at MWE below. However, positioning of subfigure on such a way is overkill solution. The same result you will get without od use `adjustbox` by adding subfigure position option as @Tom show in his answer (+1).

Another possible solution:

Package `subcaption` version 1.3 also support `\subfloat` instruction defined in older `subfig` package. Using it, the figure code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,  
            position=top,
            ]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[b][Short caption]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subfloat[b][Longer caption that spills over to next line]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]